# Setfacl not working only one file

Tags: rhel, setfacl

I have set a face for the SSL folder in the Rocky Linux distro. The folder has default rx for my custom user. But when new SSL & key files are created. Certificate files have proper rights, but the key file does not. So I have a problem accessing the key file.

This is the result of getfacl for the folder where the SSL & key are stored.

```
 getfacl  /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/xyz/domains/
# file: usr/local/directadmin/data/users/xyz/domains/
# owner: diradmin
# group: diradmin
user::rwx
user:myuser:r-x
group::--x
mask::r-x
other::--x
default:user::rwx
default:user:myuser:r-x
default:group::--x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::--x
```

This is the result for the newly created .key file inside that folder.

```
getfacl /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/xyz/domains/example.com.key
# file: usr/local/directadmin/data/users/xyz/domains/example.com.key
# owner: diradmin
# group: access
user::rw-
group::r--
other::---
```

Comment: what creates the new file? You're showing that `.../data/users/xyz/domains/` has default ACLs, but then the file you look at later is in `.../data/users/myuser/domains/`, is that on purpose?

Comment: No it's my mistake to change user names to myuser&example.com, I fixed it now. The new SSL files are created by DirectAdmin.